# issue with Loading TopoJSON File in D3.js: Map Not Displaying Properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.min.js" integrity="sha256-tHoAPGoNdhIR28YHl9DWLzeRfdwigkH7OCBXMrHXhoM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Choropleth Map</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id='canvas'></svg>
</body>
<script defer src='script.js'></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

```js
let countyURL = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Saw-mon-and-Natalie/a11f058fc0dcce9343b02498a46b3d44/raw/e8afc74f791169a64d6e8df033d7e88ff85ba673/canada.json'
let eduURL = 'https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json'

let countyData
let educationData

let canvas = d3.select('#canvas')

let drawMap = () => {
  canvas.selectAll('path')
    .data(countyData)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.geoPath())
    .attr('class', 'county')
}
d3.json(countyURL).then(
  (data, error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      countyData = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.provinces).features

      d3.json(eduURL).then(
        (data, error) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error)
          }
          else {
            educationData = data
            console.log('Education Data')
            console.log(educationData)
            drawMap()
          }
        }
      )

    }
  }
)
```

`I'm working on a project to create a choropleth map using D3.js. I have successfully implemented the map using the FreeCodeCamp provided TopoJSON file for the USA. However, when I try to use a different TopoJSON file for Canada, the map doesn't display properly.

I've tried using two different TopoJSON files for Canada:

1. [Canada TopoJSON File 1](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Saw-mon-and-Natalie/a11f058fc0dcce9343b02498a46b3d44/raw/e8afc74f791169a64d6e8df033d7e88ff85ba673/canada.json)
2. [Canada TopoJSON File 2](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Brideau/2391df60938462571ca9/raw/f5a1f3b47ff671eaf2fb7e7b798bacfc6962606a/canadaprovtopo.json)

In both cases, while the SVG element is generated with paths, nothing actually shows up on the map. It's worth noting that when using the USA file, the map displays correctly.

I have ensured that I've modified the code to accommodate the differences in the TopoJSON files (e.g., changing **`counties`** to **`provinces`**), but the issue persists.

Any insights into why the map isn't displaying correctly with the Canada TopoJSON files would be greatly appreciated.`

Comment: The USA topojson is preprojected - it contains pixel coordinates. Your topojson has unprojected coordinates: lat long pairs. Since you don’t apply a projection (d3.geoPath() won’t apply a projection if you don’t supply one to it), you treat your lat long pairs as pixels, but as Canada has negative longitude values, your feature appears to the left of the SVG (and thus is not visible). You need to apply a projection to your data.